# React-Native: useSearchParams hook from 'expo-router'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo-router

I am a beginner learning react native. I want to use the `useSearchParams` hook from 'expo-router', but I get the error message:
`error: TypeError: 0, _expoRouter.useSearchParams is not a function (it is undefined)`

So maybe the `useSearchParams` hook doesn't exist anymore (I am following this from a tutorial).

This is my code:

```
import { Stack, useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'expo-router'

const JobDetails = () => {
  // get specific ID of job details page we are on
  const params = useSearchParams();
  const router = useRouter();

  const { data, isLoading, error, refetch } = useFetch("job-details", {
    job_id: params.id,
  })

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite}}>
      <Stack.Screen></Stack.Screen>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default JobDetails
```

Am I correct in thinking that `useSearchParams` doesn't exist anymore? If so, I have come across `useLocalSearchParams` and `useGlobalSearchParams`. What are the use cases for both?
Which would therefore be better to use in my example above?

Comment: I don't see any `useSearchParams` hook in the docs, but I do see [`useGlobalSearchParams`](https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/hooks/#useglobalsearchparams) and a [`useLocalSearchParams`](https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/hooks/#uselocalsearchparams) hooks exported. If you want to learn about their differences see [Use search parameters](https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/search-parameters/).